# JQuery - exclude timezone in Date()

Tags: jquery, arrays, date, object

I am working on formatting an existing date. Here's what I did:

```
var fromFormat = settings.dateRange.from.split("-");
settings.dateRange.to = new Date(fromFormat [2] + "-" + fromFormat [0] + "-" + fromFormat [1]);
```

It seems by declaring it as "new Date()," the timezone is automatically being pushed.

This gives me the output:

"Mon Jun 01 2015 08:00:00 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time)"

I only need "Jun 01 2015"

I need to set the date as an object because I'll be needing .getMonth,.getDay,.getYear to work

I'm currently confused, how do I remove the timezone. I've also did multiple searches in google but never got my desired result..

Comment: Please be more clear, could you show the JSFiddle?

Comment: I just need the M-D-Y in the date. JQuery seems to automatically insert the timezone right after the M-D-Y which I don't need.

Comment: You cannot exclude the timezone from the `Date()` object. You can exclude it while formatting the output as a string like in your example `Jun 01 2015`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://momentjs.com/, this will surely help you.